# CakePHP Expire Post after X days

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Using the blog tutorial, I would like to have an option where you can see the posts on the "main" index page until the post has been active for x days. After this time period of x days I would like the post to be set as "expired" in the database. Can anyone shed some light on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: can't you just select based on date? SELECT ... WHERE `YOUR_DATE` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) ...

Comment: Yes, but I want it to physically change a value in the database to "expired".

Comment: sounds like poor design. but if you must run a cron job daily to do it UPDATE ... set expired=1 WHERE YOUR_DATE > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)

Comment: I'll explain it more. It's for a listing site where people can put their animals up for adoption, they can set how long they would like the listing to go for i.e 7-14 days. Each listing has a "status" field in the database. And it goes from Pending > Accepted > Expired || Adopted.

I need the status to change to "expired" when the listing has reached it's allotted days.

Comment: you can still do that without actully adding an extra field to the db, but if you prefer then just run a cron job to expire those listings.

Comment: Am not sure you need to set anything as expired .. all you need if improve your SQL Statement

Comment: I need to to set as expired so the user has a reference to what stage their listing is at. Currently I manually accept listings and set them from "pending" to "accepted", once I've done this the listing should show for it's allotted days and then automatically expire after x days.

Comment: again, this could be done in the query, or write a cron job to expire listings daily. Is there another question in here?

Comment: Yes, sorry. When you say this can be done in the query, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use paginate then use:

**NOTE** ***HERE $x is your intarval***

```
$this->Post->recursive = 0;
$this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(Post.created)) >' => $x)
        );
$this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
```

For normal find() use this:

```
$this->Post->find('all', 
                   array(
                    'conditions' => array('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(Post.created)) >' => $x)
                   )
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is with a SQL select statement.  MySQL has many built-in date methods.  But first, we need to define what you are trying to accomplish.  Also note that the fields we are using (`created_at`, `allotted_time`) are both `DATE` fields.

What you want to do is only display *currently running* posts.  Since we know the date the ad was started, we can subtract the started date from the current date to figure out how much time we have left before the ad expires.  This can be accomplished with the `DATEDIFF` function and the `CURDATE` function.

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `created_at`)
```

If you try to execute the above the statement you will notice that it returns an integer, the number of days that have passed since the ad was first created.  Since `DATEDIFF` returns an integer we need to convert `allotted_time` to an integer also.

```
DATEDIFF(`allotted_time`, `created_at`)
```

Now we know how much time left the ad has been running and how many days past the day it was created it has to run.  Obviously, if the ad has been running for less than the number of days between the creation date and the allotted time it is still running.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `created_at`) < DATEDIFF(`allotted_time`, `created_at`)
```

Put this all together, and we get a statement similar to this.

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `ads`
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `created_at`) < DATEDIFF(`allotted_time`, `created_at`)
```

Comment: I would like a value in the database to change to "expired", so not just have it removed from view.

Comment: Why though?  What specific action can only be obtained by adding a new column to the database?

Comment: I'll explain it more. It's for a listing site where people can put their animals up for adoption, they can set how long they would like the listing to go for i.e 7-14 days. Each listing has a "status" field in the database. And it goes from Pending > Accepted > Expired || Adopted. I need the status to change to "expired" when the listing has reached it's allotted days.

Comment: Then I am assuming that you have a start field and an allotted time field.  Am I right?

Comment: I have a created, modified and a run_time field.